# Trouble Passing object Fragment to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass an object Fragment -> Activity -> Fragment.

My 2nd Fragment says my object is null when getting arguments:

Fragment A: (Sending Object, communicator is interface to Main Activity)

```
meetsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Meet meet = new Meet();
            meet = meetList.get(position); // meet is not null here
            communicator.changeToolbarTitle(meet.getName());

            ****** Sends Meet object to main activity ********
            communicator.sendMeetToMeetProfile(meet);
        }
    });
```

Main Activity:

```
@Override
public void sendMeetToMeetProfile(Meet meet) {
    MeetAthletesListContainer meetAthletesListContainer = new MeetAthletesListContainer();

    ***** Fragment is not replaced just called *******
    MeetAthletesMales meetAthletesMales = new MeetAthletesMales();
    MeetAthletesFemales meetAthletesFemales = new MeetAthletesFemales();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    Bundle bundleMales = new Bundle();
    bundleMales.putParcelable("meetAthletesMales", meet);
    meetAthletesMales.setArguments(bundleMales);
    Bundle bundleFemales = new Bundle();
    bundleFemales.putParcelable("meetAthletesFemales", meet);
    meetAthletesFemales.setArguments(bundleFemales);

    ******* Replaces current fragment with container that contains above (2) fragments *******
    transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, meetAthletesListContainer, "meetAthletesListContainer");
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Fragment B: (Fragment is contained inside another fragment)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meet_athletes_males, container, false);
    Log.e("", "Fragment onCreateView Called!");

    initializeVar();
    *****Says this meet object is null*****
    meet = getArguments().getParcelable("meetAthletesMales");
}
```

I am replacing a fragment with another but passing the object to a fragment which is inside another fragment(meet_container_fragment). So my object is being sent directly to the fragment. I got this working in another instance where I actually replace the fragment but I want to replace the FRAGMENT CONTAINER, not the actual fragment B

Comment: transaction.replace will remove all fragment and add new fragment. Perhaps use transaction.add?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  MeetAthletesListContainer meetAthletesListContainer = new MeetAthletesListContainer();

        ***** Fragment is not replaced just called *******
        MeetAthletesMales meetAthletesMales = new MeetAthletesMales();
        MeetAthletesFemales meetAthletesFemales = new MeetAthletesFemales();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("meetAthletesMales", meet);
        bundle.putParcelable("meetAthletesFemales", meet);
        meetAthletesFemales.setArguments(bundle);

        ******* Replaces current fragment with container that contains above (2) fragments *******
        transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, meetAthletesListContainer, "meetAthletesListContainer");
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I don't think you really changed anything here

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

main activity

```
     FragmentB fragmentb = FragmentB.newInstance(appContext,meet);
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.contentContainer, fragmentb , tag);
```

Fragment B

```
    public static FragmentB newInstance(AppContext appContext, Meet meet) {
    FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_APP_CONTEXT, appContext);
    args.putString(ARG_MEET_NAME, meet.name);
```

}

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        appContext = (AppContext) getArguments().get(ARG_APP_CONTEXT);
        name= getArguments().getString(ARG_MEET_NAME);
         }
}
```

also make Meet implements Serializable

Comment: I will try this but was wondering if adding/replacing a different fragment instead of Fragment B will have an impact on Fragment B getting the bundle. In my program, Fragment B is contained inside another fragment I will be replacing